# Problem with matplotlib.pyplot with matplotlib.pyplot.scatter in the argument s

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

My name is Luis Francisco Gomez and I am in the course Intermediate Python > 1 Matplotlib > Sizes that belongs to the Data Scientist with Python in DataCamp. I am reproducing the exercises of the course where in this part you have to make a scatter plot in which the size of the points are equivalent to the population of the countries. I try to reproduce the results of DataCamp with this code:

```
# load subpackage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## load other libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## import data
gapminder = pd.read_csv("https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/287/datasets/5b1e4356f9fa5b5ce32e9bd2b75c777284819cca/gapminder.csv")
gdp_cap = gapminder["gdp_cap"].tolist()
life_exp = gapminder["life_exp"].tolist()

# create an np array that contains the population
pop = gapminder["population"].tolist()
pop_np = np.array(pop)


plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp, s = pop_np*2)

# Previous customizations
plt.xscale('log') 
plt.xlabel('GDP per Capita [in USD]')
plt.ylabel('Life Expectancy [in years]')
plt.title('World Development in 2007')
plt.xticks([1000, 10000, 100000],['1k', '10k', '100k'])

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

However a get this:

[image]

But in theory you need to get this:

[image]

I don't understand what is the problem with the argument **s** in **plt.scatter** .

Comment: Sorry is plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp, s = pop_np*2). I correct the mistake and the problem is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scale your s,

```
plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp, s = pop_np*2/1000000)
```

> The marker size in points**2.
>   [Per docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

Comment: Thank you Scoot Boston. This is really strange in the course DataCamp they don´t have this problem. Maybe they rescale the array and they don´t show that to the student. Thank you for you help. Sorry if this was an stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your sizes are too large, scale it down. Also, there's no need to create all the intermediate arrays:

```
plt.scatter(gapminder.gdp_cap, 
            gapminder.life_exp, 
            s=gapminder.population/1e6)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for editing my post Quang Hoand in the case of the images and also for answering my question. Remember that I am new to Python so maybe in the process I make unnecessary steps because I am following an online course. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
plt.scatter(gdp_cap, life_exp, s = gdp_cap*2)
```

or maybe reduce or scale pop_np

Comment: Thank you for your help @simomod. I had never used stackoverflow but this resource is fantastic.